# match() values with tolerance

Tags: r, subset, floating-accuracy

I'm subsetting a dataset before plotting, but the key being numeric I cannot use the strict equality testing of `match()` or `%in%` (it misses a few values). 
I wrote the following alternative, but I imagine this problem is sufficiently common that there's a better built-in alternative somewhere? `all.equal` doesn't seem to be designed for multiple test values.

```
select_in <- function(x, ref, tol=1e-10){
  testone <- function(value) abs(x - value) < tol
  as.logical(rowSums(sapply(ref, testone)) )
}

x = c(1.0, 1+1e-13, 1.01, 2, 2+1e-9, 2-1e-11)
x %in% c(1,2,3)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
select_in(x, c(1, 2, 3))
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: @Frank nope :) please post as an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to achieve the goal (albeit not quite with a tolerance):

```
fselect_in <- function(x, ref, d = 10){
  round(x, digits=d) %in% round(ref, digits=d)
}

fselect_in(x, c(1,2,3))
# TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: ref being numeric in my case, I had to round both x and ref to the same precision

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how much better it is but `all.equal` has a tolerance argument that will work:

```
`%~%` <- function(x,y) sapply(x, function(.x) {
 any(sapply(y, function(.y) isTRUE(all.equal(.x, .y, tolerance=tol))))
})

x %~% c(1,2,3)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

I don't like having two apply functions there. I'll try to shorten it.

**update**

Another way that might be faster without using `all.equal`. It turns out to be much faster than the first solution:

```
`%~%` <- function(x,y) {
out <- logical(length(x))
for(i in 1:length(x)) out[i] <- any(abs(x[i] - y) <= tol)
out
}

x %~% c(1,2,3)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

**Benchmark**

```
big.x <- rep(x, 1e3)
big.y <- rep(y, 100)

all.equal(select_in(big.x, big.y), big.x %~% big.y)
[1] TRUE

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  baptiste = select_in(big.x, big.y),
  plafort2 = big.x %~% big.y,
  times=50L)
Unit: milliseconds
     expr       min        lq      mean    median       uq      max
 baptiste 185.86828 199.57517 231.28246 244.81980 261.7451 271.3426
 plafort2  49.03265  54.30729  84.88076  66.10971 118.3270 123.1074
 neval cld
    50   b
    50  a
```

Comment: I wonder in what the second solution is different from OP's one.

Comment: It's close, but I think it's different enough to possibly add value.

Comment: you're looping over x, while I was looping over ref, so it's different. In my particular case  `length(ref) << length(x)`, so if a loop must be used it's probably better to do it my way.

Comment: fair enough, I guess the function call is what makes the difference. Thanks.

Comment: Frank's answer is great. What function call?

Comment: You have `tol` as a global var read inside these functions? I guess there's no other way, since you're making a binary operator..?

Comment: Yes, for the binary operators. Similar performance as argument also.

Comment: It's actually a bit faster with the arg defined.

Comment: Ok, interesting. I guess I'd consider doing `options( eqtol = 1e-10 )` and grabbing `getOption("eqtol")` inside the function so as to be less likely to accidentally modify it. (I have no experience actually doing such a thing, though.)

Answer (score 2):

Another idea to avoid `length(x) * length(ref)` searching:

```
ff = function(x, ref, tol = 1e-10)
{
    sref = sort(ref)
    i = findInterval(x, sref, all.inside = TRUE)
    dif1 = abs(x - sref[i])
    dif2 = abs(x - sref[i + 1])
    dif = dif1 > dif2
    dif1[dif] = dif2[dif] 
    dif1 <= tol
}
ff(c(1.0, 1+1e-13, 1.01, 2, 2+1e-9, 2-1e-11), c(1, 2, 3))
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

And to compare:

```
set.seed(911)
X = sample(1e2, 5e5, TRUE) + (sample(c(1e-8, 1e-9, 1e-10, 1e-12, 1e-13), 5e5, TRUE) * sample(c(-1, 1), 5e5, TRUE))
REF = as.double(1:1e2)

all.equal(ff(X, REF), select_in(X, REF))
#[1] TRUE
tol = 1e-10 #set this for Pierre's function
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(select_in(X, REF), fselect_in(X, REF), X %~% REF, ff(X, REF), { round(X, 10); round(REF, 10) }, times = 35)
#Unit: milliseconds
#                                    expr        min         lq     median         uq        max neval
#                       select_in(X, REF) 1259.95876 1324.52371 1380.10492 1428.78677 1495.61810    35
#                      fselect_in(X, REF)  121.47241  123.72678  125.28932  128.56770  142.15676    35
#                               X %~% REF 2023.78159 2088.97226 2161.66973 2219.46164 2547.89849    35
#                              ff(X, REF)   67.35003   69.39804   71.20871   73.22626   94.04477    35
# {     round(X, 10)     round(REF, 10) }   96.20344   96.88344   99.10093  102.66328  117.75189    35
```

Frank's `match` should be faster than `findInterval`, and indeed is, with most time spent in `round`.